# Prove: (M − N) ∪ (N − P) ⊆ (M ∪ N) − (M ∩ N ∩ P) are there mistakes or is my proof incomplete?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, proof-writing, solution-verification

$$(M\setminus N) ∪ (N\setminus P)=$$

$$(M\cap N^c)\cup(N\cap P^c)=$$

$$(M\cup N)\cap (M\cup P^c)\cap (N^c\cup P^c)\cap (N\cup N^c)=$$

$$(M\cup N)\setminus[(M \cup P^c)\cap (N^c\cup P^c)]^c=$$

$$(M\cup N)\setminus[(M\cup P^c)^c\cup(N^c\cup P^c)^c]=$$

$$(M ∪ N)\setminus[(M^c\cap P)\cup(N\cap P)]=$$

$$(M ∪ N)\setminus[P\cap(M^c\cup N)]=$$

$$(M ∪ N)\setminus[P\cap(M^c\cup N)\cap (M\cup M^c) ]=$$

$$(M\cup N)\setminus[P\cap(M^c\cup(M\cap N)]=$$

$$(M ∪ N)\setminus[(P\cap M^c)\cup (P\cap M\cap N)]=$$

I am worried about mistakes and logical leaps. Is this proof incomplete? At the end, do I need to show/how do I show that $${(M\cup N)\setminus[(P\cap M^c)\cup (P \cap M\cap N) ]}\subseteq(M\cup N)\setminus(M\cap N\cap P) $$ 
Are there any other mistakes. Any help/verification/general insight is greatly appreciated.

Comment: $N\cap\neg N\equiv 0$

Comment: ty for the catch, was just a typo. it says (N∪¬N) now, which is the domain and not an empty set. Are there any other errors? Im specifically worried about lacking something in the last statements

Comment: So far, so good, well-done @brettF! However, I changed negation into complement since this is a set operation!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **contraposition** now:
$$(M\cup N)\setminus[(P\cap M^c)\cup (P \cap M\cap N) ]\equiv(M\cup N)\cap[(P\cap M^c)\cup (P \cap M\cap N) ]^c$$
$$A\subseteq B\equiv B^c\subseteq A^c$$

---

**explanation:**
$$(P \cap M\cap N)\subseteq[(P\cap M^c)\cup (P \cap M\cap N)]\equiv[(P\cap M^c)\cup (P \cap M\cap N)]^c\subseteq(P\cap M\cap N)^c$$

---

**extra:**

$$A\setminus(B\cup C)\equiv A\cap(B\cup C)^c\equiv\underbrace{A\cap B^c\cap C^c}_{X}\equiv X$$
$$A\setminus C\equiv A\cap C^c\equiv A\cap C^c\cap(B^c\cup B)\equiv\underbrace{(A\cap B^c\cap C^c)}_{X}\cup\underbrace{(A\cap  B\cap C^c)}_{Y}\equiv X\cup Y$$
$$\implies X\subseteq X\cup Y$$

Comment: thank you for the reply. I am still confused. How can I show $$A - ( B ∪ C) ⊆ ( A - C ) $$?

Comment: @brettF, you may see what I added in the morning.

Comment: So helpful! Thanks.

Comment: @brettF, you're welcome!